# Get ID of image and change image JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, css

I have a question that was i hard to find the solution. 
I want to change my image by using javascript. 
I have 50 image in my project.
I write the image ID one by one example:

"in this code example i write the img src and class until img class 50"

```
<div id="image">
    <img src="default.jpg" class="img-1" /> <img src="default.jpg" class="img-21" /> <img src="default.jpg" class="img-41" />  </div>
```

My question is,
How i can change the image with a different image using only javascript? 
its not button onclick.

img class 1 until 20 the image is (plant.jpg) and  img class 21 until 40 the image is (animal.jpg)  and img class 41 until 50 the image is (default.jpg)

Anybody understand what i mean?

How change source using javascript?  please answer with full and understanding code because i am new with javascript.

Thank you!!

Comment: I doubt anyone understood it.. Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Check this code, this is how you can loop all your img tags https://jsfiddle.net/wgy89L6b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions:

1. I believe that I'm understanding your problem correctly.
2. I assume you are using jQuery library

In that case, you can run each function, split the class and detect the number (eg. 1 or 5 or 10 etc) then do the rest.

example code:

```
// Find all images inside "image" id
$("#image").find("img").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        getClass = $this.attr('class'), // get class of this image
      splitClass = getClass.split("-"); // split the class by "-"

      if(splitClass[1] <= 20) {
       // If image class has number equal or below 20 (eg. img-1, img-2....)

        // Update the image source accordingly
        $this.attr("src", "plant.jpg");

      } else if (splitClass[1] <= 40) {
      // If image class has number equal or below 40
        $this.attr("src", "animal.jpg");


     } else {
        // Else condition - Rest of the image

        $this.attr("src", "default.jpg");
      }      

});
```

You can find running example in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jimbatamang/954fkLr0/2/).

I hope, it will solve your problem.

Cheers,
Jimba

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById("YouImgID").src = "NewImgSrc.png";

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can loop through all img tags

```js
$('img').each(function(){
alert($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="1" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="2" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="3" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="4" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="5" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="6" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="7" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="8" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="9" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
<img id="10" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

2 way of doing this is given here-

### Pure Javascript-

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = "http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg";
}
```

```html
<img id="myImg" src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg">

<p>Click the button to change the value of the src attribute of the image With Javascript.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Change The Image</button>
```

### jQuery-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("img").attr("src", "http://www.pxleyes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/baby/89.jpg");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/small-baby-posing-1732780.jpg"><br>
<button>Change The Image</button>
```

### Update-

I am giving an example for changing the image with `ID` not `class`.

And give example for only one image.

If u like u can use this for multiple images with multiple IDs.

ID is more applicable than class here because `id` selects only one element but `class` multiple elements.

A video tutorial for this is given **[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Knf0_caU4gk)**.

More can be found [**W3Schools Tutorial**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp) and [**Mozilla Developer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image).